# Misaligned Radio button text

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, layout-inflater

I have radio buttons in my app, that I add dynamically through code.

Here is the layoutdefinition of the group I add the buttons to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/answer_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RadioGroup>
```

Here is the code where I dynamically add the radio buttons:

```
for (String value : values) {
   RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) ViewGroup.inflate(context,
            R.layout.radio_button_layout, null);
   radioButton.setText(value);
   answersRadioGroup.addView(radioButton);
}
```

With `radio_button_layout` being:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/font_color_gray"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

My problem is that my text gets disaligned to the radio buttons like that (I am concerned with the vertical alignment):

[image: disaligned radio buttons]

I am certain this is not a common case, obviously, but can someone hint me into where should I look to try to identify my issue?

**EDIT**: 
Actually I realized it is better if I use `AppCompatRadioButton` as I am aiming at app compatibility. Now this is changed (also in question's sources), but it has no difference.

**EDIT2**
Here are the relevant styles, at least accordung to me:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/MyRadioButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Styling the font of the radio buttons -->
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

As one can see I use custom button icon now, but the problem was there even without using the custom icon.

**EDIT3**
Now it gets even more interesting. I am sure the misalignment is caused by the inflation.

I have tried modifying the `RadioGroup` layout as follows:

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/answer_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/font_color_gray"
        android:text="Alabala"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

And then appended the actual radio buttons with the code included above. The result is as follows:
[image]

As you can see the radio button in the layout is correctly aligned vertically, but the inflated buttons are not. Please, any ideas?

Comment: Interesting fact, that for me it looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lwiEi.png (just copied your code and added it to the empty solution; running on Lollipop). Have you tried with clean project - do you have this behaviour there too?

Comment: Also, few thoughts: you don't need `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`. And your issue looks like you have somewhere `radioButton.setPadding(0,0,0,XXX);` (or `android:paddingBottom="XXdp"` for your `AppCompatRadioButton` i.e. bottom padding has being set somewhere) or some custom theming in code behind.

Comment: I am using the activity as context. I am testing on several devices KitKat and Lollipop. I have cleaned the project thousand times. I agree abt `layout_gravity`, but it does not hurt either. I don't seem to find neither padding nor anything else i have missed sharing with you.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev can you try to compile and run [this test-project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jry7f7xk3cnu15q/radio_buttons.zip?dl=0) and share with us, if it also shows radiobuttons misaligned? Also, just an extra thought - check, that your com.android.support:appcompat support library is  "fresh".

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov Thanks for the huge efforts you put in helping me. I am just about to start this experiment. I will create the project by myself, though, as I have the project I encounter the problem in configured for ADT.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev You're more than welcome. I've uploaded [APK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3uj6y0elyd3lw9/radio_buttons.apk?dl=0) so you can try without compilation. If it works, then we know, that the problem is not with the code above (at least, with latest Support lib(v7:23.1.1), buildToolsVersion "23.0.2")

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov The issue has been identified and it has nothing to do with layouts or anything. The `values` are retrieved from a backend of mine and apparently there was invisible character in them that caused the misalignment. Changing the `setText` to `setText(value.trim())` fixed the misalignment. I feel stupid. I prefer my bounty does nto get wasted, so i do not mind awardin git to you if you post something as an answer, however I wonder whether this is the correct behavior according to the community?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Great, that you've figured out! Actually, I had this idea yesterday. I had to voice it.. :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're 2 different reasons which can be root cause for such sort of issues:

- `AppCompatRadioButton` has `paddingBottom` set in code behind/in layouts
- Invisible characters in `text` property (in the exact this question it was the reason behind the issue)